# How to find the angle of image edges at each pixel using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I need to find a matlab algorithm to find the angle of image edges at each pixel. Using canny edge detector, I have found the edges of my sample image as in the following image:[image]

Could you please help me to understand whether there is a matlab built in function or algorithm that can be used to find the angle of image edges at each pixel for the above image. Canny edge detector algorithm only gives information about the location of edges. How can I use the location of edges to find the angle at each pixel using matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lucky you, reading the docs solves your problem!

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/edge.html#d122e65852

> `[BW,threshOut,Gv,Gh] = edge(___)` also returns the directional gradient
> magnitudes. For the Sobel and Prewitt methods, Gv and Gh correspond to
> the vertical and horizontal gradients. For the Roberts methods, Gv and
> Gh correspond to the gradient at angles of 45° and 135° from
> horizontal, respectively. This syntax is valid only when method is
> 'Sobel', 'Prewitt', or 'Roberts'.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I read the docs but what I am looking for is the angle (direction) of edges at each pixel using the edge location for example, but I could not find the function that has this feature in docs.

Comment: Yeah, Gv and Gh give you that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.